# Use _tcstoul to detect invalid string during unsigned long conversion - unable to treat -ve string as invalid value

Tags: c++

I try to use _tcstoul for string to unsigned long conversion.

However, it doesn't treat -ve string input as invalid input. Is there any workaround for this? Or I had missed out something?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <tchar.h>

int main() {
    {
        unsigned long iResult(0);
        TCHAR *pszStopString;
        iResult = _tcstoul(_T("2abc"), &pszStopString, 10);
        if( _tcsicmp(pszStopString, _T("")) != 0 ) {
            // OK. We reach here.
            printf("2abc : Error occur during conversion!\n");
        }
    }

    {
        unsigned long iResult(0);
        TCHAR *pszStopString;
        // iResult = 4294967274
        iResult = _tcstoul(_T("-22"), &pszStopString, 10);
        if( _tcsicmp(pszStopString, _T("")) != 0 ) {
            // Nope. We didn't reach here!
            printf("-22 : Error occur during conversion!\n");
        }
    }

    getchar();
}
```

I expect during conversion of "-22", error shouldn't occur, as "-22" is a negative value, and I am expecting non-negative value returned from _tcstoul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the missing `#include <stdlib.h>` (and also changing `<cstdio>` to `<stdio.h>`) your code seems to work:

```
C:\test> (cl /nologo- 2>&1) | find "++"
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86

C:\test> cl x.cpp & x
x.cpp
2abc : Error occur during conversion!
fine

C:\test> _
```

It's unclear (to say the least) what you mean by "-ve string"?

[EDIT]
Oh, perhaps you think you should get an underflow error. No, the [MS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k9xb7x1%28VS.71%29.aspx) say "strtoul allows a plus (+) or minus (–) sign prefix; a leading minus sign indicates that the return value is negated.". So you get negative value wrapped into the unsigned range.

Cheers & hth.,

– Alf

Comment: OK, problem solved then: you had simply misunderstood the function's contract. If you don't want to accept negative value specifications, then simply check for presence of leading minus in the string.

Comment: When you (whomever) vote down an answer, add a comment indicating why. As far as I know my answer is correct. If it isn't then I'd like to know, and other readers would benefit from the correction.